# How to create a dataset containing python files in the "Machine Readable" format?

Tags: python, dataset, kaggle

I created a [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/adeepak7/tensorflow-global-and-operation-level-seeds) that contains the python files containing snippets required for the Kaggle kernel - [Tensorflow's Global and Operation level seeds](https://www.kaggle.com/code/adeepak7/tensorflow-s-global-and-operation-level-seeds/)

Since the kernel is around setting/re-setting global and local level seeds, the nullification of the effect of these seeds in the subsequent cells wasn't possible.

Hence, the snippets have been provided as separate python files and these python files are executed independently in the separate cells.

**My question -** Kaggle is asking me to provide these files in a "Machine Readable" format. How to provide or convert these python files in the "Machine Readable" format?